# Choose to Select Value Between Two Columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just working on a personal project. I am trying to write an SQL query (`using PHP and MYSQL`) that selects the appropriate row from a table based on some condition.

I've done a bit of research and have been fiddling with it for a few days but no luck.

So, I have a table called Friendship_Request. Although the table has several columns, one of them is called `Requester_ID` and another column is called `Requestee_ID`. If one of the columns matches a value I pass in the query (say, `userID`) then I want the query to bring me back the value in the **other** column. For example,

[image]

If I pass 200 as the userID then the query should bring back 201, 400 and 901. How do you do this? Does this have a name? I didn't even know what to Google.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please include the full table structure and the code that you are working on. You can just do it in a simple query like `SELECT * FROM Friendship_Request WHERE Requester_ID = 200`

Comment: Are you querying against `Requester_ID` or `Requestee_ID`?

Comment: Well that's just it. If the value is in Requester_ID then I want Requestee_ID and if the value is in Requestee_ID then I want Requester_ID. However, I don't know that. I don't know what to select for because it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]First we fetch all the Requester_ID and Requestee_ID with values equal to userID. Then we select the Requestee_ID if the Requester_ID == userID and select Requester_ID if the Requester_ID != userID.

```
SELECT IF( Requester_ID = 200, Requestee_ID, Requester_ID ) AS Request
FROM Requester
WHERE Requester_ID = 200 OR Requestee_ID = 200
```

### Output :

Request

201

400

901

Comment: It doesn't work when there are multiples of the same value. So, if I pass in 200, it only returns 901. It returns the last instance. It's not returning 201 or 400

Comment: Oh, yea. It does work in MyPHPAdmin but not my PHP code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT if(Requester_ID=200, Requestee_ID, Requester_ID) as friendid FROM Friendship_Request WHERE Requester_ID = 200 OR Requestee_ID=200;
```

Hope this query will solve your problem.

Comment: Explaining this query will help OP. BTW, I learnt _Control Flow Functions_ exists in mysql +1

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT Requester_ID AS ID
  FROM Friendship_Request
 WHERE Requestee_ID = 200
 UNION
SELECT Requestee_ID
  FROM Friendship_Request
 WHERE Requester_ID = 200;
```